# Unable to register user in xmpp chat app

Tags: iphone, ios, chat

I want to implement XMPP framework in my iOS App, I have completed all the things in (Chatting with other users , showing presence of other users , etc.)

But the problem is , I am unable to get the new user registered from my App. I am using following code for that,

```
if ([appDel.xmppStream supportsInBandRegistration])
    [appDel.xmppStream registerWithPassword:txt_Password.text error:nil];
```

But for this, supportsInBandRegistration method always returns NO and I dont get called the method never registerWithPassword: .

Help me if any solution available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What server are you using? Some servers support in-band registration even thought they don't send the correct stream:feature according to XEP-0077. Most of them should give the feature in the disco results however.

---- OR ----
You can solve this by following code. It's working fine for me. :

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate: 
(NSXMLElement *)error; 
{ 
NSLog(@"Did not authenticate"); 

 [xmppStream registerWithPassword:[[NSUserDefaults 
standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userPassword"] error:nil]; 

NSError * err = nil; 

if(![[self xmppStream] registerWithPassword:password error:&err]) 
{ 
    NSLog(@"Error registering: %@", err); 
} 

} 
- (void)xmppStreamDidRegister:(XMPPStream *)sender{ 

NSLog(@"I'm in register method"); 

    } 

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotRegister:(NSXMLElement 
*)error{ 
NSLog(@"Sorry the registration is failed"); 

}
```

I declare the registerWithPassword:error: method in 
didNotAuthenticate: method because after connection to the server it 
is going to this didNotAuthenticate method through where my 
registration methods is working fine

Comment: I did the same thing, but now I always get xmmpStream:didNotRegister: because handleRegistration: method inside xmppStream always returns error. What's wrong with my jabber server?

Comment: The reason didNotAuthenticate is called is probably because you are trying to authenticate when xmppStreamDidConnect is called. You should register the user when xmppStreamDidConnect is called instead, because during registration you can not authenticate with the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that `[xmppStream supportsInBandRegistration]` method was returning false because i was passing Jid that was already registered in the server.

```
[xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:jabberID]];
```

changes JID worked for me.

Comment: Hi muhammadAamirALi what parameter you set in jabberID?